# Every solvable group is monomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I was reading [a paper by Frank Calegary](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~fcale/papers/S5A.pdf).
On p. 2 he states that:

> If $G$ is solvable, then Artin's conjecture follows from the fact that all such $G$ are monomial.

We recall that a finite group $G$ is monomial if every simple character of $G$ is monomial (induced by a degree 1 character).

I then had a look at [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_group) on monomial groups, which says that:

> A monomial group is solvable by (Taketa 1930).

So it appears that monomial and solvable groups are equivalent?

At any rate, only the first implication is relevant to what I am trying to achieve (proving the Artin conjecture for soluble extensions).

So I am trying to prove that every soluble group is monomial, but I am completely at a loss.

All help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually,  only every *supersolvable* group (Bray et al. 1982, Cor 2.3.5) and every solvable *A-group* (Bray et al. 1982, Thm 2.3.10) is a monomial group, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_group). Not every solvable group is monomial. For example, $SL(2,3)$ is solvable, but not a monomial group.

Calegary has an additional assumption on $G$ in his sentence before: "Suppose that $G = Gal(K^{gal}/\Bbb Q)$ has a faithful permutation representation of degree $n≤ 5$."